# Should I set useRef refs or the ref.current as a part of the context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In React.Context examples, I generally see states being passed as the actual state being passed.

However, I haven't seen an example of React.Context passing a ref.  If we want to provide it to the context are we supposed to pass the ref or the actual current value?

```
const AuthenticatedClientContext = React.createContext();
export const AuthenticatedClientContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const authenticatedClientRef = useRef(unauthenticatedClient);
  const tokenRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (tokenRef.current) {
      // ref.current is passed because the token is expected to be valid and if it changed just
      // create a new client rather than reusing and have an interceptor to populate
      // the Authorization header.
      authenticatedClientRef.current = buildAuthenticatedClient(tokenRef.current) 
    } else {
      authenticatedClientRef.current = unauthenticatedClient
    }
  }, [tokenRef]);
  // This will continously run a function with a delay per call (regardless of error until cancelled). Shown later.
  useEffectPolling(async () => {
    tokenRef.current = someRandomValue()
  }, 5000);
  return (
    <AuthenticatedClientContext.Provider
      value={{
        authenticatedClient: authenticatedClientRef.current, // should I use this 
        authenticatedClientRef, // or this ?
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthenticatedClientContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useAuthenticatedClientContext() {
  return useContext(AuthenticatedClientContext);
}
```

Ideally I want

```
  const { authenticatedClient } = useAuthenticatedClientContext();
  authenticatedClient.get("whatever');
```

rather than

```
  const { authenticatedClientRef } = useAuthenticatedClientContext();
  authenticatedClientRef.current.get("whatever');
```

The code for useEffectPolling (not really relevant to the question, but will at least give some context).

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} UseEffectPollingReturnType
 * @property {boolean} active indicates that the async function is actively running.
 * @property {() => void} cancel can be invoked to cancel the polling and any active async function
 */
/**
 * This will continously run a function with a delay per call (regardless of error until cancelled).
 * @param {() => PromiseLike<void>} asyncFunction
 * @param {number} interval time between calls to the asyncFunction
 * @param {boolean} immediate if true it will run the asyncFunction immediately before looping
 * @returns {UseEffectPollingReturnType} cancel? pause? resume? active?
 */
export function useEffectPolling(asyncFunction, interval, immediate = true) {
  const timeoutRef = useRef(null);
  const promiseRef = useRef(null);
  const [active, setActive] = useState(immediate);

  /**
   * Clears the timeout if present and then cancels any promise that is active.
   * Done in that order to ensure that the promise does not get executed before the timeout is cleared.
   */
  const cancel = () => {
    if (timeoutRef.current) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
    }
    if (promiseRef.current) {
      promiseRef.current.cancel();
    }
  };

  /**
   * @returns {Promise<void>}
   */
  const wrappedAsyncFunction = async () => {
    setActive(true);
    try {
      promiseRef.current = cancelable(asyncFunction());
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error in polling", e);
    }
    timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(wrappedAsyncFunction, interval);
    setActive(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (immediate) {
      wrappedAsyncFunction();
    } else {
      timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(wrappedAsyncFunction, interval);
    }
    return () => cancel();
  }, []);

  return { active, cancel };
}
```

Comment: I think it might not matter that much in your case. `authenticatedClientRef`, a ref, is just a simple object with a single property named `current`. One difference in approach I believe is that if you pass an object (`authenticatedClientRef`) you're passing it by reference and if you pass `authenticatedClientRef.current` you're passing by value. So that might influence what you want to do. But if you only want to read the value from the context inside the components contained in your provider it's probably fine to pass `authenticatedClientRef.current`.

Comment: It seems like either way your `Provider` is not going to re-render with the new value since refs are mutable by design.  If that's the expected behavior then I would pass the whole ref object.  If you want changes in the client to trigger updates in components that use your context hook then you should be storing the client as a state instead of a ref.

Comment: @LindaPaiste it sounds like if my authenticatedClientRef.current changes (because I have a new bearer token) I should pass the the authenticatedClientRef as if I use my "ideal" it would return the original client and not the updated client in case I change the ref.  As such I have to pass the ref rather than the current, right?